# Read parameter on the server side sent by using volley Android

Tags: servlets, parameter-passing, android-volley

Okay so here is the android code for sending the volley request with the parameters.

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
            url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    pDialog.hide();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    pDialog.hide();
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", "xyz");
            params.put("email", "abc@xyz.info");
            params.put("password", "password123");

            return params;
        }

    };

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
```

And i need help in reading these values on server side using **java servlet**. I have tried finding for an answer everywhere, but i could not find anything online. 
Also i am not sure of android code being perfect. please point out a mistake if so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so you have to do the following.

```
   private void ServerRequest() {

    String emailId = email_id.getText().toString();
    String pass = password.getText().toString();

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("email", emailId);
    params.put("password", pass);

    CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, Const.url_login, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                stopAnim();
                Log.d("Response: ", response.toString());
                String s = null;
                s = response.getString("info");
                if (s.equals("Login successful")) {

                    session.createLoginSession(email_id.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
                    Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomViewIconTextTabsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(login);
                    finish();
                }
                else {
                   //handle the else condition here

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Crouton.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "Error Occured during login!", Style.ALERT,
                        (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.croutonview))
                        .show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError response) {
            Log.d("Response: ", response.toString());
            if (response instanceof TimeoutError || response instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                Crouton.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "Connection Timeout", Style.ALERT,
                        (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.croutonview))
                        .show();


            } else if (response instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                //TODO



            } else if (response instanceof ServerError) {
                //TODO
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Server Error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                stopAnim();

            } else if (response instanceof NetworkError) {
                //TODO

            } else if (response instanceof ParseError) {
                //TODO

            }

        }
    });
    int socketTimeout = 5000;//5 seconds - change to what you want
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

    // Cancelling request
    // ApplicationController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().cancelAll(tag_json_obj);
}
```

Above code is to make custom request using volley.

Server side code is as under.

```
    Map m=request.getParameterMap();
    Set s = m.entrySet();
    Iterator it = s.iterator();
    int index=0;
    String email=null,password=null;

        while(it.hasNext()){

            Map.Entry<String,String[]> entry = (Map.Entry<String,String[]>)it.next();

            String key             = entry.getKey();
            String[] value         = entry.getValue();


            System.out.println("Key is "+key);

                if(value.length>1){    
                    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                         System.out.println( value[i].toString());
                         switch(key)
                         {
                         case "email": 
                             email=value[0].toString();
                             break;


                         case "password": 
                             password=value[0].toString();
                             break;



                         }
                    }
                }else
                {
                     System.out.println("Value is "+value[0].toString());                    
                     switch(key)
                     {
                     case "email": 
                         email=value[0].toString();
                         break;


                     case "password": 
                         password=value[0].toString();
                         break;


                     }
                }



        }
```

hope this helps you.. :)